# How do I assert that a minimum duration was met in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

JMeter has a [Duration assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Duration_Assertion), which specifies the amount of time that a call should complete.

But I am looking for the inverse of that, that is I want to ensure that the operation took a minimum amount of time.  Say for login and penalty to prevent trying out multiple user accounts in rapid succession.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [JSR223 assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion).  This code block shows how to check that it has a minimum of 1 second for the processing time

```
AssertionResult.setFailure(prev.time < 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion), it allows you setting a very custom pass/fail criteria.

Example:

```
def minimumAcceptedTime = 5000

if (prev.getTime() < minimumAcceptedTime) {
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
    AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('Response time was less than expected')
}
```

where

- `prev` stands for the **prev**ious [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) class instance
- and `AssertionResult` is for the [AssertionResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/assertions/AssertionResult.html)

More information: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes)